# JSON API - DirectException("Request body is not unjson()-able: %s" % body)

Tags: json, bash, curl

I am trying to perform an action of my application API.

Below is the request -

```
-X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"action": "TriggersRouter",     "method": "updateTrigger", "data": [{"uuid": "6913aa37-6e1c-4b2f-944f-e5a642e080aa", "enabled": "True", "name": "TestAPI", "rule":{"source":"("/AIX/CPU" in evt.event_class)"}}], "type": "rpc", "tid": 1}'
```

I am getting below response -

> raise DirectException("Request body is not unjson()-able: %s" % body)
>   DirectException: Request body is not unjson()-able: {"action":
>   "TriggersRouter",     "method": "updateTrigger", "data": [{"uuid":
>   "6913aa37-6e1c-4b2f-944f-e5a642e080aa", "enabled": "True", "name":
>   "TestAPI", "rule":{"source":"("/AIX/CPU" in evt.event_class)"}}],
>   "type": "rpc", "tid": 1}

Please help me know where I am wrong.

Thanks,
Gowrish

Comment: The JSON you're sending has unescaped quotes within a string value `{"source":"("/AIX/CPU" in evt.event_class)"}` rendering the content invalid. try `{"source":"(\"/AIX/CPU\" in evt.event_class)"}` instead

Comment: Perfect thank you!!!